# How do I create a relationship between User and followers with Code 1st Entity framework

Tags: c#, entity-framework, asp.net-core

How do I create a many to relationship between User and followers with Code 1st Entity framework. I tried using the following code

```
  public class User : IdentityUser<int>
    {
        public string FirstName { get; set; }
        public string LastName { get; set; }

        public List<User> Followers { get; set; }
      
    }
```

but it doesnt seem to work

Comment: In what way is it not working? How can you tell? If there are errors, please share them.

Answer (score 0):

To create a self-referencing relationship you will need to explicitly configure the relationship. For a start you will need to nominate a null-able FK for the follower to link back to the main user.  Declaring that as a FK property would be something like:

```
public class User : IdentityUser<int>
{
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
    
    public int? FollowingUserId { get; set; }
    public virtual User FollowingUser { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<User> Followers { get; set; }      
}
```

From there you would need to configure the mapping. Using modelBuilder that would be something like:

```
modelBuilder.Entity<User>()
    .HasOptional(x => x.FollowingUser)
    .WithMany(x => x.Followers)
    .HasForeignKey(x => x.FollowingUserId);
```

You can use a Shadow Property for the FK:

```
public class User : IdentityUser<int>
{
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
    
    public virtual User FollowingUser { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<User> Followers { get; set; }      
}

modelBuilder.Entity<User>()
    .HasOptional(x => x.FollowingUser)
    .WithMany(x => x.Followers)
    .HasForeignKey("FollowingUserId");
```

Which tells EF to use a FollowingUserId column in the table without two sources of truth for the relationship in the entity. (user.FollowingUserId vs. user.FollowingUserId.UserId)

From there you could also consider making the relationship single-direction from follower to followed without the Followers collection. (Single-direction relationships are generally easier to maintain and cause fewer issues than bi-directional ones)

```
public class User : IdentityUser<int>
{
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
    
    public virtual User FollowingUser { get; set; }
}

modelBuilder.Entity<User>()
    .HasOptional(x => x.FollowingUser)
    .WithMany()
    .HasForeignKey("FollowingUserId");
```

You can still get a list of Followers for a particular user:

```
var followers = context.Users.Where(x => x.FollowingUser.UserId == userId);
```

Though it can make certain types of querying more complex, such as if you wanted to list all users with a count of their followers. (Requiring a `GroupBy` without the navigation reference for EF to work a query out with)

One additional point I would recommend would be to keep the IdentityUser separate from the "User" or such that gets displayed and related to one another. IdentityUser will have details in it relating to authentication and authorization that you won't want exposed or potentially tampered with when updating details about users and their relationships to one another. For instance if we have a "Blogger" and a "User" where User equals Authentication and Blogger represents users of the system in the scope of relationships and general persona details, Blogger can contain a UserId (or User can have a BloggerId) without a navigation reference to avoid accidentally leaking authentication information if you were to serialize entities for instance.